# Webpack import window module to a namespace

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I am using 2 modules, that are using "window.ModuleName" to export themself. Both of them use the same ModuleName.

`window.z = a;`

`window.z = b`

The first module `a` is standalone module, as I am importing it through `$.getScript`, when it is needed.

The second module `b` is bundled through webpack.

Module `a` `window.z` overwrite module `b` `window.z` when is loaded. Therefore, I would like to change the scope of the module `b` by assigning it to a variable or a namespace with webpack instead of window scope through webpack or any other possibility.

`newScope.z = a`

Both modules are not defined by me, therefore, I cannot change the export.
Is there any way to do that in professionally?

Comment: Have you looked at `script-loader`? https://github.com/webpack/script-loader

Answer (score 0):

create a startup.js file (to be included/required before you need a or b) where you do this:

```
require('a')
var z1 = window.z
window.z1 = z1
require('b')
```

now window.z1 is the a.z, and window.z is b.z, yo have them both

Answer (score 0):

I could only solve that through using string replace loader from webpack and replace the export of module `b` from `window.z => window.zb`.

Unfortunately it seems there is no possibility to change the scope of a variable from window global object to local one.